# Xcode - Search bar for iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

For my tableview I want to include a Search bar.
I searched for it, how I can do that, but the only thing I found, was tutorials for iOS 7. Thats with newer versions not compatible.

Do anyone have a tip or code, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set your own UISearchBar and add it as subview to the navigation controller. It will work also for iOS8.

```
  UISearchBar *customizeSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:...];
  customizeSearchBar.delegate = self;

  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:customizeSearchBar];
```

This is just an example I found :
http://jduff.github.io/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/